# What is GCC and minGW, and how are they related to C++ ?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, jetbrains-ide

In the IDE InteliJ, also by Jetbrains, you download and define a path to the JDK and write your code in the code editor. I am learning C++ right now and am confused as to why I need to download MinGW and G++. What is there purpose and what is their function? I am sorry if this is an overly stupid question but I am still quite new to how IDEs and libraries work and would greatly appreciate any help regarding this question or any resources that might answer them for me.

Comment: Roughly speaking gcc and mingw are compilers. You need them for compile your code into machine native executables. What tutorial/curse ate you following for learn c++? SO has a list of linkof resourses for learn several different languages

Comment: `GCC` is the language itself. It is `"C++"`. The `IDE` is just a glorified text editor with hooks to the compiler (`GCC`).

Answer (score -2):

C++ is a compiled language. A compiler creates executable snippets from source code that can be assembled into a program. You need to download that stuff because Jetbrains is not a compiler.

You have plenty of resources [online](https://www.coronadoenterprises.com/tutorials/cpp/cpp_ans.html) as what a compiler does. The link is quite dated though.

MinGW is "Minimalist GNU for Windows", The GNU toolchain is a set of apps that helps with building applications (and more). In that toolchain there is the GNU compiler collection GCC. The c++ compiler within that collection is g++.